# Markdown previewer page has weird white outlines at the side / bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

So I’m creating a markdown previewer project and I have noticed that when I inspect it with google dev tools, and I set to, for example, the iPhone 12 version of the page, it shows a weird white outline at the right side of the page. On some other phone versions the outline appears at the bottom instead.
[Here is a screenshot of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaGCX.png)
And here is a link to the project:
https://codepen.io/Henriksonn/full/GRPpxqr
I noticed that removing the media query below removes the outline, but that of course also removes the necessary styles too.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  #editor-div{
    width: 80vw;
  }
  #preview-div{
    width: 80vw;
  }
}
```

I have tried pretty much any potential solution I could come up with in order to remove those outlines, but so far nothing has worked. So i need some help to figure out how to remove them

Comment: Sometimes the scaler of DevTools can render some weird 1px wide artifacts if the webpage is scaled down. For me the white line is gone when I change the 73% scale to 100%. It could be the white background of the html element. Because you have set a background color on the body element. You might want to move that background to the html element instead.

Comment: Adding the background color to the html element doesn't change anything, but the outline does indeed disappear when I change the scaling.

Comment: Please create a snippet in StackOverflow (the `<>` button). This will preserve the original problem so others can learn from your question (the same way you certainly found StackOverflow posts).